# WP7 - XNA to Silverlight navigation back Gesture issue

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am having total reverse issue. I have main screen set as Silverlight and from that, i go the XNA code which actually plays my game.

Now the issue is that first time when i navigate from SL to XNA, it works fine since my gestures are not set. Here I set my gestures. Now i navigate back to first screen (silverlight). From there i click 
Play button again to open my xna code. Here it gives me TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable == true by default which is causing issue to my game play.

I need to make sure that when user navigate from XNA to Silverlight, all gestures should be disabled so when user navigate again from SL to XNA... it works fine.

Can anyone please help me since i have been stuck from 2 days and not getting any solutions.

Thanks in advance.
Jacob

Comment: Cany anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

When navigating back from XNA find your last function working in XNA and in the end add

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.None;
```

This will disable `TouchPanel` in XNA recieving gestures.  Next time you navigate to XNA, enable gestures you need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your creating SilverlightXNA project.

Have you tried setting this in overriden method onNavigetedFrom in your gamePage?